# Imports unresolved when manually configuring build path

Tags: java, build, google-api

In attempting to create my first executable file using Maven I encountered problems and am now attempting to use install4j instead. In order to retain my dependencies, I have downloaded the jars listed in my pom.xml, added them to the build path, and removed pom.xml. Now, some of my jars seem not to have imported correctly. I have tried both the latest versions, and the older versions that were working fine in my maven project, neither work.

The ultimate problem I'm trying to solve is that when I built with install4j my exe wouldn't run, which I assumed to be due to the dependencies in my pom.xml not being included (as I wasn't building using maven)

These are my jars:

- google-api-client-1.3.2.jar
- google-api-services-sheets-v4-rev614-1.18.0-rc.jar
- google-oauth-client-jetty-1.31.4.jar
- commons-io-1.3.2.jar (don't
  think this is used)

These are the imports that are working:

- import
  com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
- import
  com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
- import
  com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
- import
  com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
- import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

These are the imports that are not working:

- import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
- import
  com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
- import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
- import
  com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
- import
  com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
- import
  com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

This is a MRE of my code:

```
package misc;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collections;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

public class GoogleSheetsStuff {
    
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens2";

    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = GoogleSheetsStuff.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static Sheets buildService () throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        return service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don;t have to manually download and add jars to your classpath to be included in your project runtime. All you need is a Fat jar. Here is an example on how you can create one :-

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html

Comment: Using the maven assembly plug-in (to create an executable jar) was what I was trying to do when I encountered my original problems. The jar won't run. Unless the idea here is to add the fat jar to my build path and then use install4j to create the executable? The ultimate problem I'm trying to solve is that when I built with install4j my exe wouldn't run, which I assumed to be due to the dependencies in my pom.xml not being included (as I wasn't building using maven)